# How do I reference an image that I have created in an table array in Corona (Lua)?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Apologies for the incredibly noob question, but I'm new to Lua, very very rusty at any code, stuck and can't find the solution!

I'm creating a series of random images on screen using:

```
for count = 1, 6 do
 r = math.random ( 1, 5 )
 mpart[count] = display.newImage ("mpart" .. r .. ".png")
 mpart[count].y = 680
 mpart[count].x = x
 mpart[count].spawnednew = false
 x = x + 170
 mpart[count]:addEventListener ("touch", onTouch)
end
```

How do I know which object is being touched/moved in the function "onTouch", and how do I add a property to it, e.g.

```
mpart[1].spawnednew == true
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `onTouch` function should have an `event` parameter passed in. The touched image can then be found by in `event.target`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes, I'm able to reference the touched image using event.target, but how do I add a property to that target that I can reference later? E.g. permanently mark it as "moved".

Answer (score 2):

Well first off, lins is spot on about how to reference the touched object: the 'event' parameter of the listener function includes the value 'event.target'

As for adding new data to the touched object, that's as simple as 'event.target.moved = true' and now the object has data at object.moved